# Is it possible to use itables in voila?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, voila

I'm trying to use itables to display my dataframes in a better way.

When I run my code in a Notebook, everything is working fine but when I use the voila representation, all my dataframes are displayed as if they were empty.

That's an easy example to check to behaviour:

```
import itables.interactive
import world_bank_data as wb
import pandas as pd

df = wb.get_countries()
df
```

---

The point is only to get a nice display for my dataframes, so i will be happy to try something else if someone know a solution.

Thanks !

[Notebook output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1dRP.png)

Comment: `wb.get_countries()` this returning empty data

Comment: I've added the notebook output, wb.get_countries() doesn't return empty data